# Using ASM to get the reference returned via ARETURN bytecode instruction

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I have a method which returns a value that is generated in another method similar to this:

```
public static FileChannel open()
{
    return provider.newObject();
}
```

So the bytecode of the method roughly looks like this:

```
INVOKEVIRTUAL org/test/Helper.process ()Lorg/test/MyObject;
ARETURN
```

I have a Java Agent which uses ASM to do bytecode-transformation when the JVM starts up.

Now I would like to inject code which access the returned MyObject without doing too much changes to the invoke itself, i.e. ideally I would just add some bytecode instructions before the ARETURN.

Which ASM/bytecode construct allows me to access the object that is returned here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something simple, you can just put a `DUP` instruction in there followed by the desired use. If you need to inject more complex code, you should store it in a register (it doesn't really matter which since it won't be used after your code except in the exceedingly unlikely event that `areturn` throws an exception and there's an exception handler for it in the method).

So if you're using register 0 it would go like
`astore_0`
(your code) `aload_0` `areturn`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only have access to return statement IMO easier will be to use [AdviceAdapter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/AdviceAdapter.html)

It has `onMethodExit(int opcode)` method, which can be overridden in following manner :

```java
public void onMethodExit(int opcode) {
    if( opcode != ARETURN ) {
           return;
    } 
//put yout code here
}
```

Also I recommended to read http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf .

Comment: Thanks, that's a good advice, unfortunately my plumbing is already existing, so I am not able to use AdviceAdapter easily.

Comment: You can try to make a chain of visitors instead of just one, or you can use a Tree API, where you have direct access to list of instructions.